# Remove all but 1 type of character from String?

Tags: javascript

So I'm having some issues with removing all characters except two from a string.

So for instance, if I had the string "Hello World, it's pretty out", and my character was "e" and "h", I'd hope to get the result "hee".

Anyone have any ideas on this? Thanks!

Comment: I have lots of ideas, but we need to see what you've already tried and what issues you are facing with those attempts.

Comment: What have you tried and what issues are you having exactly?

Comment: Seems a case to use regular expressions

Comment: Also, your title says 1 type, but the question asks about 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help

```js
let string = "Hello World, it's pretty out";
let response = string.match(/(h|e)/gi);
console.log(response);
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great, really appreciate the help. Sorry for the lack of code, I don't know any regex.

Comment: Note that this is case-sensitive, so it's only returning the two e's as the H is capital.

Comment: Sorry my bad, fixed it.